# heroku deployment error springboot & angularjs

Tags: angularjs, heroku, spring-boot

heroku deployment error springboot & angularjs

I want to deploy to heroku an app i made but i have the following error log when accessing the app

angularjs files are in the resources/public file
no @Controller in teh code, only @RestControllers

```
heroku logs
2016-10-13T13:20:33.599545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-10-13T13:20:33.584354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-13T13:25:42.179094+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d36a2ab by gabrielvoicujpi@gmail.com
2016-10-13T13:25:42.179155+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by gabrielvoicujpi@gmail.com
2016-10-13T13:25:42.400208+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-13T13:25:42.400213+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-13T13:25:42.801854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-13T13:25:49.483010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 43279 target/*.war`
2016-10-13T13:25:51.505462+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-10-13T13:25:51.516519+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-10-13T13:25:52.141324+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding zee-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war into /app/target/tomcat.43279/webapps/expanded
2016-10-13T13:25:52.141429+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.43279/webapps/expanded
2016-10-13T13:25:52.802705+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:25:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2016-10-13T13:25:52.802715+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-43279"]
2016-10-13T13:25:52.837120+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:25:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2016-10-13T13:25:52.837123+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016-10-13T13:25:52.843373+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2016-10-13T13:25:52.843376+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2016-10-13T13:25:52.844718+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2016-10-13T13:25:52.844720+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-10-13T13:25:53.074753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-10-13T13:25:53.544355+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2016-10-13T13:25:53.544339+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:25:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2016-10-13T13:26:00.615921+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:26:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637149+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2016-10-13T13:26:00.615944+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637154+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637158+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637158+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637156+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637160+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637160+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637161+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637162+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637163+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637163+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637164+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637164+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637165+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637179+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637180+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637182+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637183+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637184+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:77)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637185+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637186+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637186+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637187+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637188+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-10-13T13:26:00.637188+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638936+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 13, 2016 1:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638937+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638938+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638939+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638940+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638940+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638941+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638942+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638942+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638943+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638944+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638943+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638945+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638945+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:261)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638958+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638955+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638961+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638962+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638960+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638963+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638964+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638965+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638962+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.638965+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639458+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639613+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639544+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639681+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:261)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639808+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639920+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639863+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.639984+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640041+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 2 more
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640152+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640281+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640401+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 4 more
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640513+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640217+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640343+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640658+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640727+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640588+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
2016-10-13T13:26:00.640785+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-10-13T13:26:01.036824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-13T13:26:00.946067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=demowebsitezee2.herokuapp.com request_id=c52590a1-7379-4c49-a312-ebe64e2bae29 fwd="5.2.224.229" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6250ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-10-13T13:26:01.073458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-10-13T13:26:01.335026+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=demowebsitezee2.herokuapp.com request_id=99691c07-53eb-4759-a246-d22843a6fee8 fwd="5.2.224.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zee</groupId>
    <artifactId>zee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Zee</name>
    <description>Zee's Personal Website</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Can you please tell me what to do ? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "when accessing the app"? Could you be more specific as to when/how this error occurs?

Comment: i get those errors in the logs...